# Connman agent RequestInput loop

Tags: c++, glib, dbus, connman

I am implementing a connman DBUS client using glib.
I've implemented `net.connman.Agent` DBUS server. But when I try to connect to some `net.connman.Service` the method `RequestInput` of my Agent is called again and again and again... with the same service object name and the same fields:

```
"Passphrase" 
Type : 'psk'
Requirement : 'mandatory'
```

How do I know why this happens? Is there some connman log I can see?
There is nothing in  `journalctl -f -u connman`.

Comment: Which connman version are you using? Did you check if you provided the correct passphrase? Try using connmanctl, you should get the error through the console display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my bad. I've been returning passphrase as a string instead of a variant.
I wish connman would notify about such errors, instead of just asking for a passphrase again and again.